# Is it possible to capture right click button event over a link in IE?

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, bho

I'm trying to develop an IE BHO (Add-on) and I'm interested in adding an option to the context menu, but only if the right click occurs over a link.

Is this possible using [SpicIE framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SpicIE)?

I've seen that the framework offers options to capture multiple events, but right click button is not on the list.

If this is not possible with SpicIE, I'll be glad to listen to any comments on alternative ways to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should not use SpicIE for any production application. Your simplest bet would be to add a Context Menu extension; see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753589.aspx for details. Otherwise, you have to override IDocHostUIHandler, and it's an extremely non-trivial exercise.

Comment: Thanks, very usefull, I used this as start point and now I have the context menu option working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible in IE.

I don't know how well it will work with other browsers though, or IE9, which is a lot more standards compliant.

Here you can see an example where they detect the mouse-button clicked with Javascript. The examples should be rather self-explanatory. They also show how to block the mouse-button click event of being triggered.

http://www.rgagnon.com/jsdetails/js-0061.html

Comment: Thanks, but this detect the right click in a Javascript insede an HTML, what I'm looking for is a way to detect this from an Add-on, a complement, that would work on every instance of IE, so I need something page independent.

Comment: No such thing would be possible, unless you would use ActiveX components or Silverlight on-desktop offline applications.